# Class variables declaration position in java

Tags: java

Most of us write class variables  at the beginning of a class but  i found some of the programmers declare class variables at the end of the class.Is there any specific reason?

Comment: Is that open source code you can post a link to?

Comment: It also makes some sense to declare a class variable right before any methods that access it, especially with large classes. That way, you don't have to scroll just to see what variable you just worked with.

Comment: i am new to stack ! may i know why i rated down for this Q?

Comment: @jayanth it's because there's no real 'decent' answer to the question that's objective - it's not a personal attack.  Any question for which any answer is subjective at best will likely be closed.  I didn't downvote you - but whoever did should have explained this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People tend not to scroll all the way down.  If you want to hide code from other developers then the end of the source file is the best place.